# Mongodb error during mup setup

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor-up

I got this error during the `Start Mongo` phase after running the command `mup setup`

`docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mongodb (aa9c0b32c40688cb3eb949ab358fb2d71326c3e4aa1155e2668c37f84c4aad6c):  (COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -d 172.17.0.2 --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT' failed: ).`

running `systemctl status firewalld` gives the following output;
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Docker tried to add `netfilter` rule for exposed MongoDB port 27017. But for some reason call of `iptables` binary failed.

To begin with, do you have `iptables` package installed on your (host) system? What user is your Docker daemon running as (or default)?
What is your Linux distribution? 
Also, try to check system logs to see if Docker left any other details of failure.
As a more advanced meassure, you may try to start Docker daemon in a debug foreground mode:

```
service docker stop
docker daemon -D
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't know much about docker as it should all be done automatically by meteor up and I don't own the container. I'm not sure what you mean by the user the docker daemon is using. I'm using centOS.

Comment: if it's a permission-related issue, then probably yes. Docker engine will check if rule already exists and would not attempt to add it again.

If the problem is caused by something like missing iptables package, then probably no

Comment: Do you think [this](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/634) issue might be related

Comment: I tried adding the line but it doesnt seem to work. How would I check for a missing iptables package?

Comment: I think this issue may be related, because on Docker service restart Docker would try to add back iptables rules